# Non recursive makefile for manu sources directories with flat .obj directory

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have project with many sources directories. But there is requirement to hold all .obj files in one flat directory, e.g.

- src1
- src2
- src3

  - src4
  - src5

    - src6
    - src7
- src8
- obj
- makefile

I have list of all sources files with directories they are located in.
With make version 3.81 I have used mixed implicit and normal rules but with make 3.82 I cannot accomplish this.
The goal is not to use shell commands only make built-in functions.

```
OBJECTS = $(subst .c,.o,$(SRCS))
OBJECTS_OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS)))

SRCDIR = $(dir $(SRCS))

vpath %.c $(SRCDIR)

   ...

$(OBJ_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c
    @echo "======================================================================="
    @echo "COMPILATION:" $< " --> " $@
    @echo "======================================================================="
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(INCL) $< -c -o $@
```

Where SRCS is list of all sources files.

Is it possible to achieve it without recursive makefiles or without using shell commands.

Comment: This makefile looks good (except the strange `$(OBJ_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c` line-- did you mean `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c`?). What goes wrong?

Comment: $(OBJ_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c and $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c is ok. When I use first one it compiles on make 3.81 but not compiles on 3.82. So as makefile docs suggest use second approach $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c but then the build error is shown that there is no rule to build first .c file from SRCS.

Answer (score 0):

Simply include a makefile that create explicit dependencies:

```
# Makefile
OBJ_DIR:=objects
SRC_FILES := $(notdir $(SRCS))

all: $(SRC_FILES:%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

tmp_srcs := $(SRCS)

include $(foreach dummy, $(SRCS), object_rule.mk)

$(OBJ_DIR)/.sentinel:
    mkdir -p $(dir $@) && touch $@
```

The trick is in the combination of the include statement and a foreach. The foreach will generate as many "object_rule.mk" as there are files listed in SRCS. The included makefile, object_rule.mk simply generates the object rule for the corresponding source file like this:

```
ifeq (,$(tmp_srcs))
$(error this makefile requires the variable tmp_srcs to be set)
endif

src_path:=$(word 1, $(tmp_srcs))
ifeq (1, $(words $(tmp_srcs)))
tmp_srcs:=
else
tmp_srcs:=$(wordlist 2, $(words $(tmp_srcs)), $(tmp_srcs))
endif

src_file:=$(notdir $(src_path))
obj_file:=$(src_file:%.c=%.o)

$(OBJ_DIR)/$(obj_file): $(src_path) $(OBJ_DIR)/.sentinel
        $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(INCL) $< -c -o $@
```

Note that I have added a dependency to $(OBJ_DIR)/.sentinel for correct and accurate dependencies.

This solution doesn't need to be hand crafted. You could probably use the [GNU Make Standard Library](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/)